# Test Case with Known Solution for 3D Navier Stokes Equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, numerical-analysis, testing

Is there a test case for 3D incompressible Navier Stokes Equations like the [Taylor vortex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%E2%80%93Green_vortex) in two dimensions?

I know, I can easily construct 3D [manufactured solutions](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6943/manufactured-solutions-for-incompressible-navier-stokes-how-to-find-divergenc) but I would like to have something more physical.

Comment: Stokes flow is probably your best bet, since you can use Green's functions (Stokeslets) to construct solutions analytically for simple geometries (alternatively, streamfunctions). The classic examples tend to be 2-D, and other classic physical flows, such as Poiseuille flow, Couette flow, and stagnation point flows tend to be 1-D, or maybe 2-D at best. These could, of course, be rigged up in 3-D, but that doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: Didn't know about Stokeslets. I will have a look into it. Maybe I can add some convective elements to get manufactured solutions with some physical meaning.

Comment: Taylor-Green vortex can also be used for verification and convergence rate checks for 3D codes, its not exclusive only for 2D codes.

Comment: Why do you care if they are physical for a benchmark problem? Only seems to matter if you want to show your numeric better resolve some feature than competitor X at resolution Y for compute time Z on vendor A's new chip B at frequency C....

Comment: I agree, partially. A manufactured solution should also inhibit certain complexities. But, OK, something physical is mainly nice for presentation.

Comment: Acutally, there was already a large list here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60476/exact-solutions-to-the-navier-stokes-equations

Answer (score 4):

Chapter 7 of the (free in PDF form) book "[I do like CFD, Vol. 1](http://cfdbooks.com/cfdbooks.html)" collects many different known solutions for multidimensional flows that can be used for benchmarking.

Comment: This looks like a pretty helpful resource. The example for the 3D incompressible Navier-Stokes equations is the Ethier-Steinman solution mentioned by @dr_sam in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are several benchmarks, like the flow around a cylinder, which is described in details at the FEATFLOW web page [here](http://www.featflow.de/en/benchmarks/cfdbenchmarking/flow.html). It is a well defined configuration of a flow passing by a cylinder obstacle and values such as the drag and lift can be compared with values obtained with different softwares (a file containing the data is provided).

Otherwise there are "less physical" flows, like the Ethier-Steinman problem described [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/fld.1650190502/abstract), which however has a known exact solution.

Comment: Good point. Benchmark cases are also useful to verify code. However, I don't think that the comparison of derived quantities like *drag* or *lift* can replace the convergence analysis in the actual variables.

Comment: Indeed, it cannot replace the convergence analysis. However, I doubt that you will be able to find a problem for which you have an exact solution and that has some nice physical features.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add, the cavity flow in three dimensions. A very good reference is R. Glowinski, Handbook of Numerical Analysis, Numerical Methods for Fluids, Chapter 9, Section 44.3. Here the test is very well detailed.